# A custom rewrite rule on a PHP micro MVC framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using an MVC micro framework and i have the following .htaccess rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rewrites everything to index.php?url=(e.g. user/register/)

In a controller named "profile" i have an action "view" (that takes 2 args) which means that the URL would normally be:

```
profile/view/arg1/arg2
```

What i am trying to do is to hava a more friendly url like:

```
profile/1/profile-name
```

but when i try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ profile/view/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

it is not working.

In other words i am only trying to rewrite the original url to remove the "view" action so that anyone could visit that url just by entering the profile id (arg1) and the name (arg2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually doing is not working because you are translating to a friendly url but not to the index.php and since you defined it as L rule, then it would leave with `profile/view/1/test` which does not exist, so you could combine it with your last rule so it reads:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ profile/view/$1/$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and since the first match will transform the url, it will be passed by the second rule in the correct format. Alternatively you could just write the correct target:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?url=profile/view/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Hope that helped

Comment: actually you might want to add QSA to your profile view link as well, just in case i.e. `profile/1/test?format=json` would then map to `index.php?url=profile/view/1/test&format=json`